# HTML5 Video from a Password Protected directory in Safari

Tags: html, video, safari, cross-browser

Has anyone had a similar problem, and have found a solution?

I have a page in a password protected directory that I would like to show video on, using the HTML5 video tag (with video.js, video tag is correct, and all fallback formats are included so no issue there). The problem is that Safari does not seem to play the video files when they are in the same PW protected directory, while all other browsers do. As soon as I move the vid files are out of the PW protected directory it plays fine.

Any thoughts / solutions?

Comment: You could make an external script which serves the video, but thats inefficient, just a thought ..

Comment: Would the script fail as well with the vids being in the same folder? Worth a shot I guess.

Comment: No, as you say it works if the vid is outside the protected directory, the script would have to be outside the directory, while the video is in the directory. The script accesses the video and returns it. So you could say <video src="link_to_script"></video>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar problem and found an answer here:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2448777?start=0&tstart=0

> Your problem is an authentication error with Safari, Quicktime X, and
>   HTTP basic authorization. If you check the box to remember the
>   password in keychain then the movie plays in Safari.

Once I had Mac OS's keychain remember the password in Safari, my MP4 videos began playing in my password-protected directories!