# Password Protected Video HTML5

Tags: html, video, safari, passwords, movie

I have a video inside a password protected directory. The HTML file that loads it is outside of the password protected directory.

I have .mov, .mp4, and .webm versions of the video in the password protected directory.

Firefox and Chrome load the video fine, but Safari does not.

Here is the HTML5 Video Code I am Using:

```
<video width="700" height="400" poster="Video_Thumbnail.jpg" controls>
    <source src="dir/name.mov" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="dir/name.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="dir/name.webm" type="video/webm">

    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

What modifications do I have to make to the code to be able to play it on Safari and on iOS Devices?

Comment: Thanks for telling us about your project. What is your question?

Comment: What modefications do I have to do to make the video play in Safari or on iOS Devices?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016204/html5-video-from-a-password-protected-directory-in-safari

Comment: Possibly, however, the other post is much older, and a new version of Safari has been released. Do you know if it is still relevant?